# Traceback error for array of all ones

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm beggining at Python.
I just installed Python 3.5.3 and I tried with my first code in Shell.
I would like to creat an array with dimension 2X3 of all ones.

> > > a=ones((2,3))

But it get error:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
  a=ones((2,3))

NameError: name 'ones' is not defined

Actually, I read about it but I still don't understand why it is error.

What is going wrong with my software?

Thanks in advance for your answer,

Chuong

Comment: [`ones`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html) is a [`numpy`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/) function and not in the standard library of python. you need to install numpy (using `pip` or somehow else - depending on your platform).

Comment: what are you going to do with array full of ones?